# How to write a factory function to initialize a constexpr reference in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I want to initialize a constexpr reference by a factory function, but I failed to succeed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct IWorker // common interface of workers
{ virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

template <typename T> // example worker
struct Worker : IWorker
{ T& Target;
  const T Source;
  constexpr Worker(T& target, const T& source) : Target(target), Source(source) {}
  virtual void foo() const { puts("Worker::foo"); Target = Source; }
};

template <typename T> // factory for Worker (and maybe others)
constexpr const Worker<T>& factory(T& target, const T& source)
{ return Worker<T>(target, source);
}

struct R // allow array of references
{ const IWorker& ref;
};

int iVal = 0;

constexpr R table[] 
{ { Worker<int>(iVal, 7) } // works
//, { factory(iVal, 8) } // does not work
};

int main()
{ printf("iVal = %i\n", iVal); // iVal = 0
  table[0].ref.foo();
  printf("iVal = %i\n", iVal); // iVal = 7
  return 0;
}
```

OK, I could call all the constructors directly but I would prefer a factory because

1. I do not need to repeat the type argument(s) over and over and
2. the factory could also select the appropriate worker class depending on the argument list (overloads) or even constexpr properties of the arguments.

The problem is probably somehow related to the static storage required by the static reference.

Is it *impossible* to write a factory for this purpose?

- If yes, **why?**
- If no, **how to implement it correctly?**

The intended use cases are large parser dispatch tables with, of course, more complex classes.
The language standard is C++11. Nevertheless it would be good to know if C++17 could help, although it is not yet supported widely.

Comment: @Jorge Y. your solution was quite close: removing the `const` from the factory did the trick. You should undelete and update it. Probably `const`prevents RVO.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a r-value reference in `R` and have your factory return a `Worker<T>` so it can bind to a r-value reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct IWorker // common interface of workers
{
  virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

template <typename T> // example worker
struct Worker : IWorker {
  T &Target;
  const T Source;
  constexpr Worker(T &target, const T &source)
      : Target(target), Source(source) {}
  virtual void foo() const {
    puts("Worker::foo");
    Target = Source;
  }
};

template <typename T> // factory for Worker (and maybe others)
constexpr Worker<T> factory(T &target, const T &source) {
  return Worker<T>(target, source);
}

struct R // allow array of references
{
  IWorker &&ref;
};

int iVal = 0;

constexpr R table[]{
    {Worker<int>(iVal, 7)} // works
    , { factory(iVal, 8) } // does not work
};

int main() {
  printf("iVal = %i\n", iVal); // iVal = 0
  table[0].ref.foo();
  printf("iVal = %i\n", iVal); // iVal = 7
  table[1].ref.foo();
  printf("iVal = %i\n", iVal); // iVal = 8
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The r-value reference seems not to be the important part of the story. The return type of the factory must be *by value* and it must be *non-const*.